# What data cleaning method is best to be adopted for price=$0?

Tags: data-transformation, exploratory-data-analysis

Suppose I have an AirBnb dataset. In EDA, i noticed that some room price are 0 (as shown in the example below). Is removing them a best approach since its not possible that a room price is 0? Or should I replace with the mean values?

```
AirBnB name    Host   Host_is_superhost Price  Min_nights   Max_nights  Availability_365 Long Lat
Ritz Stay      Rina         Y             0        3            300           300        3.4  -1.2
Cartel         Josh         Y             0        4            30             10        1.2 -1.23
```

Comment: If you know for a fact that for some reason any missing data are replaced with 0s then it might be a good idea to impute them.  I can't imagine why this would be the case however, but you would know better than me.  Additionally, imputation with the sample mean is one approach, but a better approach would be multiple imputation. See Harrell's book *Regression modelling strategies* for more.

Comment: Thank you @DemetriPananos would it be feasible if i impute with the mean price of the city/ town that the AirBnb belongs to?

Comment: That may or may not be a good idea. In the case where there is only a hand few of airbnbs in the city, the estimate could be biased due to other factors you have failed to consider.

Comment: The dataset is actually similar to NY Airbnb dataset from Kaggle, im not quite sure why some prices are 0. Would imputation with sample mean be biased as well as some cities may have lower average price? Im considering removing it (cons: some important data will be deleted) or assume that price=0 means it is unavailable etc..